# How can I create a activity into a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

Here is the code. but has error.
the error line has been marked. and error is nullpoinerexception. Anyone could help me?

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View setting_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_layout, container, false);


        Button buttonClickChangeArea = (Button) setting_layout.findViewById(
                R.id.Button_setting_settingarea);
 <=error==> buttonClickChangeArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetAreaActivity.class);
                // Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                // intent.putExtras(extras);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return setting_layout;

    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the error? post logcat please

Comment: Did you define the SetAreaActivity in the manifest ?

Comment: The NPE is because `buttonClickChangeArea` is null; so check that a view with id `Button_setting_settingarea` really exists in the layout.

Comment: Without a stacktrace it could also be the intent that is null.

Comment: i don't think so `getActivity()` needed for starting activity, change `getActivity().startActivity(intent);` to `startActivity(intent);` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename your view. It is the same name as your layout so change from

```
View setting_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_layout, container, false);
```

to

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_layout, container, false);

Button buttonClickChangeArea = (Button) view.findViewById(
            R.id.Button_setting_settingarea);
```

Must be sure that your Button is in setting_layout.xml file with id of Button_setting_settingarea.

Also sure that your ***SetAreaActivity*** registered in your manifest.xml file.

Comment: Same name can be conflicted. that's why.

Comment: View can have the name setting_layout.

Comment: and also its layout name has also setting_layout.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes you right, but Are You Sure this cause conflict? because i don't think so

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Yes it may be. Because i can't see any other things for getting error. also  i have mentioned all other things in my answer.

Comment: "Also sure that your SetAreaActivity registered in your manifest.xml file." I missed this.

Comment: Okay.. Wel come.. Glad to help you!!